# Unknown protocol: protocolId = 92, protocolName = CbdProto, servicePrimitive = REQUEST

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I try to implement a Network Layer Protocol, using the INET SensorNode module. I properly extend the NED simple module as follow :

```
simple CbdProto extends NetworkProtocolBase like INetworkProtocol
{
    @class(inet::CbdProto);
}
```

This protocol is added to the list of the INET Procotol class (Protocol.cc) by extending that class :

In ProtocolNew.h

```
static const ProtocolNew CbdProto;
```

In ProtocolNew.cc

```
const ProtocolNew ProtocolNew::CbdProto("CbdProto","Network Protocol",ProtocolNew::NetworkLayer);
```

The C++ class is settled up accordingly. I register the protocol in initialize() method :

```
void inet::CbdProto::initialize(int stage) {
    if (stage == INITSTAGE_NETWORK_LAYER) {
        registerProtocol(ProtocolNew::CbdProto, gate("transportOut"), gate("transportIn"));
    }
}
```

The .ini file is as follow :

```
**.hasIpv4 = false
**.hasIpv6 = false
**.hasGn = true
**.generic.typename = "SimpleNetworkLayer"
**.generic.np.typename = "CbdProto"
```

But I keep having this error that I don't know to fix it.

```
 <!> handlePacket(): Unknown protocol: protocolId = 92, protocolName = CbdProto, servicePrimitive = REQUEST, pathStartGate = WsnCbd.s[0].udp.ipOut, pathEndGate = WsnCbd.s[0].tn.in[0] -- in module (inet::MessageDispatcher) WsnCbd.s[0].tn (id=18), at t=0s, event #6
```

Please, I will appreciate your input.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't have to create a new class. You just have to add your new protocol to the Protocol.cc and .h file, to the existing `Protocol`. (Don't forget to create an instance in the `.cc` file.
2. Your new protocol provides a **service** to the upper layer so you have to use `registerService()` in your protocol's code.

Comment: Hi @Rudi, I tested and it works. Thanks for your input.